# RowMapper strange result

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a Spring application that use JdbcTemplate to query the database, and the result from the rowmapper is different from the result of the query.

My query returns :

```
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| ORIGINATING_SYSTEM | SYS_REF | CUR1 | CUR2 | TRADE_DT | START_DT |  END_DT  | BOOK_REF | BOOK_ID |    NOMINAL     | ORIGIN_VALUE_DT |
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| CC                 | 4000000 | USD  |      | 01/04/19 | 01/04/19 | 01/04/19 | TDCZK    |     317 | -8245872154,55 | 29/03/19        |
| GPS                | 4000000 | EUR  |      | 01/04/19 | 28/03/19 | 28/03/19 | TDCZK    |     317 |       55555550 |                 |
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

This result is processed with a rowmapper to get a list :

```
public List<Trade> findBackValueTrades() {
    List<Trade> trades = getJdbcTemplate().query(FIND_BACK_VALUE_TRADES, new BackValueTradeMapper());
}

class BackValueTradeMapper implements RowMapper<Trade> {

    public BackValueTradeMapper() {
    }

    @Override
    public Trade mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Trade trade = new Trade();

        trade.setOriginatingSystem(rs.getString("ORIGINATING_SYSTEM"));
        trade.setSystemRef(rs.getString("SYS_REF"));
        trade.setNominal(rs.getDouble("NOMINAL"));
        Currency cur1 = new Currency();
        cur1.setId(rs.getString("CUR1"));
        trade.setCurrency1(cur1);
        Currency cur2 = new Currency();
        cur2.setId(rs.getString("CUR2"));
        trade.setCurrency2(cur2);
        trade.setTradeDate(rs.getDate("TRADE_DT"));
        trade.setStartDate(rs.getDate("START_DT"));
        trade.setEndDate(rs.getDate("END_DT"));
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setBookRef(rs.getString("BOOK_REF"));
        book.setId(rs.getLong("BOOK_ID"));
        trade.setBook(book);
        trade.setNominal(rs.getDouble("NOMINAL"));
        trade.setEnteredDate(rs.getDate("ORIGIN_VALUE_DT"));
        return trade;
    }
}
```

where Trade is just an `@Entity`, containing only fields and getters and setters :

```
@Table(name = "TRADES")
@Entity
public class Trade implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2143115773381859155L;

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "SYS_REF")
    private String systemRef;

    @Column(name = "ORIGINATING_SYSTEM")
    private String originatingSystem;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUR1")
    private Currency cur1;

    // remaining fields + getters/setters
}
```

The problem is in the resulting list, where it seems the trade from `CC` was overwritten :

```
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+
| ORIGINATING_SYSTEM | SYS_REF | CUR1 | CUR2 | TRADE_DT | START_DT |  END_DT  | BOOK_REF | BOOK_ID |  NOMINAL  | ORIGIN_VALUE_DT |
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+
| GPS                | 4000000 | EUR  |      | 01/04/19 | 28/03/19 | 28/03/19 | TDCZK    |     317 |  55555550 | 29/03/19        |
| GPS                | 4000000 | EUR  |      | 01/04/19 | 28/03/19 | 28/03/19 | TDCZK    |     317 |  55555550 | 28/03/19        |
+--------------------+---------+------+------+----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Why is that ?

By the way, I was able to resolve the issue by extending the `Trade` class and overriding equals and hashCode, but I want to know why it worked.

Comment: Oops sorry, I've fixed the mapRow return type (`Trade` is the parent class)

Comment: I looked at the JdbcTemplate source code, I don't see anything that would cause this and then be solved with an implementation of the equals and hashCode methods. I'd double check the query and the associated results as well as the fix you perceive to be working.